# Difference Between setEntityMethod and SetRequestEntityMethod

Tags: java

I am writing a Java Application and I am sending my `CSV file(2000 records)` as a request Body. I came across two methods of two different Classes. `setEntity(HttpPost Class)` and `setRequestEntity(PostMethod Class)`. Can anybody explain both its working? Which method is better to send the request body?

Comment: Did you read javadocs for given classes?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.

**Commons HttpClient (legacy)**

Commons HttpClient 3.x codeline is at the end of life(which uses `postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);`).

All users of Commons HttpClient 3.x are strongly encouraged to upgrade to HttpClient 4.1 (`postMethod.setEntity(requestEntity);`).

**Reference:**

[Apache HTTP](https://hc.apache.org/)